# Webdesign MVC - going in the right direction?

Tags: php, mvc

I am trying to learn webdesign using the MVC design pattern. Right now, I am stuck at a point where my code gets more complex, and I am unsure about the structure and where to put which code parts.

I started with an index.php file as my controller, which right now does not much more than loading the Slim framework to render the different views

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){  
$app->render('header.php');  
$app->render('content.php');   
$app->render('footer.php');  
});  
$app->run();
```

Then I built a complex content.php where I do a lot of form data logic,
reading from a server directory, and echoing the results mixed with html tags. That surely will violate the MVC pattern, right?

What is the general approach to this? Should I put all the logic inside the index.php, store the results in an array, and pass that to the framework's render function, like this:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){ 

//Do something and store results in an Array

$app->render('header.php', anArray());  
$app->render('content.php', anArray());   
$app->render('footer.php', anArray());  
});  
$app->run();
```

How can I prevent index.php becoming too complex when doing so? Is there a different approach to take?

Comment: You might use the template feature provided my slim to seperate your view files. Take a look at the docs http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html

Comment: In short - index.php is not the controller, it's generally just a sort of runner that fetches the relevant controller for the action you want to perform based on the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, you have to pass your variables into your object like this:
`$app->vars = $yourVars`

Then if you include the files inside your render function the files works as part of your object and you can access your vars like this:
`$this->vars`

Or you can also pass the vars as you thought `$app->render('file.php', $yourVars)`

That's the whole point of MVC you only pass specific variables to objects so they can't access all of them.